# SAS %sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH) doesn't exist

Tags: sas, sas-macro, enterprise-guide

I am running this simple macro:

```
%macro grabpathname ;
%sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH)
%mend grabpathname;
%put %grabpathname;
```

And I am getting the following error:

> WARNING: The argument to macro function %SYSGET is not defined as a
>   system variable.

I am using Enterprise Guide 5.1
What am I doing wrong? I need this as I want to use relative paths for my programs.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this note](http://support.sas.com/kb/36/613.html, `SAS_EXECFILEPATH` isn't defined anywhere but in DM sessions of SAS on Windows.  In EG you don't have access to that.

I would suggest considering what you're using it for.  If you're using it to identify where other programs are stored, in EG you should be able to generally avoid using that style of coding and instead incorporate all necessary programs into your EGP.  If you're using it to identify data locations or output locations, I suggest writing promts or macro variables to define that, and having a single EGP to run multiple inputs/outputs rather than copying it to multiple directories.

Answer (score 0):

One of the new features added to SAS Enterprise Guide 4.3 is the ability to have a relative reference to an external file.   Since you're on 5.1, this should apply to you as well.

*"In previous releases of SAS Enterprise Guide, the project file stored external file references as absolute paths. In SAS Enterprise Guide 4.3, these external file references are stored as relative paths, which makes it easier for you to move the project file, data, and programs to a different folder or a different machine. In SAS Enterprise Guide 4.3, use pathnames that are relative to the current location of the project file instead of using a full path."*
-- [SAS Enterprise Guide: New Features in 4.3](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/whatsdiff/63859/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1uxv844f7oio4n0zpi97g09ov4w.htm)

To enable the functionality for your Enterprise Guide project:

1. Open the project
2. File | Project Properties | File References
3. Check the box "Use paths relative to the project for programs and importable files"

Comment: this is only working for SAS programs though, not excel files or any other type of file you'd like to read in SAS